# How do you switch between classes?

Tags: heroes-and-generals

I recently bought the tanker and I was in a battle with it.

The environment of the battle changed, so I wanted to switch from my tanker to my infantryman mid-battle. Is this possible? If so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to check boxes of all soldiers, you actually choose assault teams, not soldiers, so if you tick infantry, paratrooper and tanker you will queue to a match which has infantry teams, paratrooper teams and tank teams (dependent on your tanker's equipped tanks).

To switch soldiers during battle: when you die and you are in respawn screen hover bottom left to show a button to switch soldiers. In bottom right you can change ATs